# automate process continuous export of data in Azure Data Explorer to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to setup auto process of continuous export of data in Azure Data Explorer to Azure Data Lake? based on official docs it is required every time use of AAD token, so I could not configure once this export.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up using the [Continuous data export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export) process. For the storage provide the storage account key to avoid needing to renew it.

Comment: I would like to configure export to ADLS gen1, how I could do it? in doc said that I need to use AAD token, but it is expiring.

Comment: Have a look at ";impersonate" authentication method.

Comment: Continuous export isn't supported for external tables with impersonate in their connection strings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export

Answer (score 0):

I have created ticket with MS support and having answer:

I have reached our engineering team and you are correct - this scenario is currently not yet supported. Very few customers use ADLS gen1, so there has been very little demand for feature this so far. ADX does not support refresh tokens, so we cannot renew the token OBO of the service principal. I have sent your feedback on the need of this feature to the engineering team – and for long term (unfortunately no ETA right now), we plan to support using managed identities in continuous export, and then this will be supported.

In the meanwhile, our suggestion is to move to ADLS gen2, where you can configure the export with an account key (or a very long living SAS key).